# Which method is faster and why?

Tags: python-3.x, string, algorithm, type-conversion, concatenation

I was solving the problem of finding the largest number. I know the solution to this problem but I am not able to understand does the different methods of concatenating two numbers will make any difference in run time. I am using python 3.7.

> Method 1

Converting both numbers in strings and concatenating them then converting them back to integer.

```
def concatenate(num1, num2):
    num1 = str(num1)
    num2 = str(num2)
    num1 += num2
    return int(num1)
```

> Method 2

Counting the number of digits in one of the numbers and adding the same number of zeros in another number.

```
def concatenate(num1, num2):
    digits = len(str(num2))
    num1 = num1 * (10**digits)
    num1 += num2
    return num1
```

Does the difference in technique make any difference? Converting the number in string or arithmetic operation(multiplication) which one is faster and why? Does change to another language will make any difference such as compiler-based language(C++)?

Edit:

> Method 1 - Execution time 6.604194641113281e-05 seconds
>
> Method 2 - Execution time 5.245208740234375e-06 seconds

The time taken by data type conversion is more but why is it so and is it only for interpreted language like python not for compiler-based language like C++?

Comment: Just run it and see for yourself?

Comment: What exactly is this code *supposed* to do? The only reason I can think of to concatenate two numbers like this is to convert two `n`-bit numbers into a `2n`-bit number, in which case you generally know what `n` is ahead of time, and you can use bit operations: `return num1 << n | num2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there'll be a difference! It's easy enough to see for yourself:

```
import timeit

def concatenate1(num1, num2):
    num1 = str(num1)
    num2 = str(num2)
    num1 += num2
    return int(num1)

def concatenate2(num1, num2):
    digits = len(str(num2))
    num1 = num1 * (10**digits)
    num1 += num2
    return num1


num1 = int("1"*10000)
num2 = int("2"*10000)

t1 = timeit.timeit('concatenate1(num1, num2)', 'from __main__ import concatenate1, num1, num2', number=100)
t2 = timeit.timeit('concatenate2(num1, num2)', 'from __main__ import concatenate2, num1, num2', number=100)

print("t1=", t1, "; t2=", t2)
# Output:
# t1= 0.772663099996862 ; t2= 0.30340000000433065
```

Clearly, `t1` is ~2 times `t2`. Maybe the big time-sink is stringifying the number? Let's try another implementation that uses `math.log10` to figure out the number of digits:

```
import math
def concatenate3(num1, num2):
    l = math.log10(num2)
    digits = int(l) + 1
    num1 = num1 * (10**digits)
    num1 += num2
    return num1
```

Timing this function with the other two gives:

```
t1= 0.8134238999919035 ; t2= 0.32444419999956153 ; t3= 0.11973479999869596
```

This would seem to support the argument that converting the integer to a string takes a lot of time.

**Why is it so?** Because converting the integers to strings involves interpreting the binary value in the storage in using decimal digits and then assigning characters for each digit. When adding two numbers, all you do is add their binary digits together.

You will see such behavior in both compiled *and* interpreted languages. However, different languages will have different levels of slowdown associated with different methods based on how their internals work.

Answer (score 2):

While the answer provided by @pranav-hosangadi is great, and I echo his assertion that there is going to be a difference.

I want to point out though that what is the "best/fastest" solution for one set of inputs might not be the best for all inputs. Knowing what your input data "looks" like can be important when looking for a better / faster solution.

For the inputs @pranav-hosangadi chose (very large strings of numbers), his `concatenate3()` is clearly fastest. Their choice of inputs seems more than reasonable given the question is about determining something about "large" numbers.

However, if the problem where to define large numbers being those with up to ten digits (still pretty big in some cases) then their `concatenate3()` method is actually slower than the first two methods and a fourth method:

```
def concatenate4(num1, num2):
    return int(f"{num1}{num2}")
```

is the faster than all three (at least on my laptop).

Just as importantly, this new `concatenate4()` is not universally faster and for inputs in the range used by @pranav-hosangadi it performs "poorly". While their `concatenate3()` crushes the others.

```
import timeit
import math

def concatenate1(num1, num2):
    num1 = str(num1)
    num2 = str(num2)
    num1 += num2
    return int(num1)

def concatenate2(num1, num2):
    digits = len(str(num2))
    num1 = num1 * (10**digits)
    num1 += num2
    return num1

def concatenate3(num1, num2):
    l = math.log10(num2)
    digits = int(l) + 1
    num1 = num1 * (10**digits)
    num1 += num2
    return num1

def concatenate4(num1, num2):
    return int(f"{num1}{num2}")

num1 = int("1"*10)
num2 = int("2"*10)

t1 = timeit.timeit('concatenate1(num1, num2)', 'from __main__ import concatenate1, num1, num2', number=1000)
t2 = timeit.timeit('concatenate2(num1, num2)', 'from __main__ import concatenate2, num1, num2', number=1000)
t3 = timeit.timeit('concatenate3(num1, num2)', 'from __main__ import concatenate3, num1, num2', number=1000)
t4 = timeit.timeit('concatenate4(num1, num2)', 'from __main__ import concatenate4, num1, num2', number=1000)

print("t1=", 100_000*t1, "; t2=", 100_000*t2, "; t3=", 100_000*t3, "; t4=", 100_000*t4)
```

Results:

```
t1= 63.25999999999971 ; t2= 58.6299999999998 ; t3= 64.32999999999994 ; t4= 40.889999999999674
```

On my laptop, `concatinate3()` only becomes fastest when combining numbers with more than 35 digits each.

**Let's Try To Answer Why:**

Let's take a peek at some rough timings for the individual steps of `concatenate3()` and `concatenate4()`. Note that true cost of the individual steps are masked by function call overhead and thus are rough approximations but they are still based on real timing tests and illustrate an interesting point.

For 10 digit numbers over 1000 runs `concatenate3()`:

```
def concatenate3(num1, num2):  # 59 time units (accurate)
    l = math.log10(num2)       # 18 time units
    digits = int(l) + 1        # 14 time units
    num1 = num1 * (10**digits) # 12 time units
    num1 += num2               #  7 time units
    return num1
```

For 10 digit numbers over 1000 runs `concatenate4()`:

```
def concatenate4(num1, num2):  # 45 time units (accurate)
    tmp = f"{num1}{num2}"      # 30 time units
    tmp = int(tmp)             # 20 time units
    return tmp
```

For 1000 digit numbers over 1000 runs `concatenate3()`:

```
def concatenate3(num1, num2):  # 1400 time units (accurate)
    l = math.log10(num2)       #   23 time units
    digits = int(l) + 1        #   15 time units
    num1 = num1 * (10**digits) # 1341 time units
    num1 += num2               # 2119 time units
    return num1
```

For 1000 digit numbers over 1000 runs `concatenate4()`:

```
def concatenate4(num1, num2):  # 5700 time units (accurate)
    tmp = f"{num1}{num2}"      # 3500 time units
    tmp = int(tmp)             # 3100 time units
    return tmp
```

So, what can we see? First, multiplication and addition is intrinsically faster than concatenation and casting. That should be no surprise.

The interesting part is that while the cost to calculate `digits` is independent of the size of the inputs and disappears into rounding error with larger inputs, with smaller inputs this cost becomes a significant component of the total.

Comment: TIL about the underscore-in-number-literal thing. Neat!

Comment: Why is it so ? from what I know format used f strings( i can be wrong ). Isn't that also conversion as well ?

Comment: @sajankumar You are right in that `def concatenate5(num1, num2): return int(f"{num1}{num2}")` is even faster still for 10 digit strings.

Comment: IDK why the downvote. The only thing I can think of that would improve this answer is if you used more loops in the `timeit()` call for these cases (instead of multiplying the result), since you expect each loop to take less time. Using `number=1_000_000`, for example, gives me `t1= 1.1858979999960866 ; t2= 1.1826948999951128 ; t3= 1.256787299993448 ; t4= 0.7797783999994863`  -- `t1, t2, ` and `t3` are consistently in the same ballpark, and `t4` is noticeably smaller. Anyway, this answer doesn't deserve to be at -1 so here, have an upvote :)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Good idea, I'll up it to 1000 loops

Comment: I did not downvote, but I don't really see in how far this answer is useful. It just adds *yet another* means to do this, with *yet another* degree of freedom – there are possibly even more of both, but the question does not ask about them. Most importantly, the answer doesn't really say *why* any of this behaves as such.